# How to new a struct with variable array?

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

I have the following struct

```
struct Foo {
    uint32_t magic;
    uint32_t length;
    uint8_t data[];
}
```

The length gives the number of bytes in data.

How do I allocate this using new so that alignment restrictions are garanteed? I'm afraid that `new uint8_t[length+8]` might only align for uint8_t.

Further problem: A pointer can hold a Foo*, Bar*, Bla*, Blub*, ... all having a magic as first member. Most of them have static size and would be allocated with `new Bla()`. And I want to avoid needing a

```
switch(p->magic) {
    case MAGIC_FOO: delete[](p); break;
    case MAGIC_BAR: delete(p); break;
    case MAGIC_BLA: delete(p); break;
    case MAGIC_BLUB: delete[](p); break;
    ...
    default:
        std::cerr << "Don't know how to free a " << p->magic << std:endl;
        assert(false);
}
```

Does that mean I have to use malloc() for all the structs and placement new to construct them in place? That way I could call free(p) every time.

Comment: Don't.  If you want a run time sized array use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Not possible in this use case

Comment: Why not to use proper C++ containers?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  There should be an RAII way to solve it.

Comment: There is no such thing as variable array member in standard C++.

Comment: @eerorika So I'm guessing it's impossible to allocate such a C struct with new then. That leaves hiding this in C code and use malloc/free then. Thanks.

Comment: It appears you are doing C-style memory management, with C-style structs.  Use malloc/free, and initializer routines.  Don't try to have these C-style structs also have C++ facilities, like virtual functions or std::string data members.  Instead of doing `data[]` instead do `data[biggest_possible_size]` and then malloc struct size - unneeded, rather than malloc struct size + more.  Be careful, the danger of undefined behavior lurks around every turn.

Comment: @Eljay Any link why one is better than the other?

Comment: If I remember correctly, `uint8_t data[];` as as stretchy buffer (which is what the team I was on called them at the time) as the last member variable of a struct isn't legal C++.  If you ever need one to use as a temp on the stack, it will have the largest possible size already, making it convenient as a temporary or as a staging variable for constructing one that gets memcpy'd (with the properly calculated final target size) to an malloc'd object.

Comment: @eljay It's not c++, it's only C99/C11. But compilers like gcc or clang allow this as compiler extension in C++ code. The extension doesn't seem to include any provisions for supporting new though, unless you write a custom operator new for the struct that uses malloc/posix_memalign internally.

Comment: My mistake.  I thought this was a C++ question, since the question is tagged with `c++`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow When asking about language extensions, you should mention the extensions explicitly in the question. Also preferably tag them, if possible. Otherwise people will assume that you're asking about standard C++. Not everybody who knows about C++ knows about every extension on every platform out there.